# Matlab uigetfile with csvread

Tags: matlab

Very new to Matlab so bear with me. I have a code that works perfectly fine for individual *.csv files and am trying to incorporate a uigetfile prompt to enable the analysis of multiple files. I've been stuck on an error during import for the past few hours and haven't found a working solution. Here's the code in question.

```
[fname, pname] = uigetfile('*.csv', 'Select Data', 'Multiselect', 'on'); 
tempfilename=fullfile(pname, fname);

for i=1:length(tempfilename)
   Pixel=csvread(tempfilename(i));
```

Upon running the code, I get the error that "Filename must be a string." the variable tempfilename calls the appropriate files upon checking in the command window. I have tried introducing a dummy variable into the mix in an attempt to get around this issue, but then it tells me that the "file cannot be found." When using only one file, the following code worked perfectly fine:

```
file='FILENAME.csv';
Pixel=csvread(file);
```

But trying to incorporate this formatting does not make the code work in conjunction with uigetfile.

Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Comment: `tempfilename` is a cell array. Cell arrays are accessed using braces instead of parentheses. your `csvread` command will be as follows `csvread(tempfilename{i})`

Comment: As MZimmerman6less said. Just need to be careful, as when you select only 1 file, instead of many, `fname` and `pname` are `char` not `cell`s.

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly. Thanks, MZimmerman6!